# Read value from progress bar RobotFramework

Tags: robotframework

I'm trying to do this exercise http://www.uitestingplayground.com/progressbar where I want to press a button when the progress bar reaches 75%.

Here is my code

```
 Open Browser    http://www.uitestingplayground.com/progressbar  chrome
 Maximize Browser Window
 Click Button    css=#startButton
 Wait Until Element Contains    css=#progressBar.width 75
 Click Button    css=#stopButton
 Close Browser
```

Can somebody help me what is the right way to capture the progress bar status?

Comment: let us know what is the result of the above code you are getting.

Comment: First off, consider following:  Wait Until* keywords are not "instant checks". The do polling in intervals. Now, consider that one poll hits when the width is 74 and then there's small delay and then when the next poll happens, width can already by 76 .. Then, your Wait Until* is essentially going to hit a timeout because it never saw 75 in the width with this code..

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following complete code and paste in you IDE and run. This code will loop though the range but it will exit if it gets the match of the progress bar which you are looking for.

```
*** Settings ***
Library  Selenium2Library
Documentation    Test file to validate the progress bar status check

*** Test Cases ***
Progress bar status
   [Tags]    Progress bar status check 
   Open Browser    http://www.uitestingplayground.com/progressbar  chrome
   Maximize Browser Window
   Click Button    css=#startButton
   :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    100000
      ${progress}  get element attribute  xpath=//div[@class='progress-bar bg-info']  style
      run keyword if  '${progress}' == 'width: 75%;'  run keyword  click button  css=#stopButton
      Exit For Loop IF  '${progress}' == 'width: 75%;'
 END
```

Comment: Let me know if you are able to execute this snippet, I will help you further

Comment: You are the best! It works perfectly! Thank you!